# How to set a global variable from inside a loop

Tags: batch-file

So here is the batch code I am using.

```
set fullstring=
set string=testago
echo %string%>x&FOR %%? IN (x) DO SET /A strlength=%%~z? - 2&del x

for /L %%a in (1,1,%strlength%) do (
    set b=%%a - 1
    set c=%%a
    set this=%string:~%%b,%%c%
    set fullstring=!fullstring!%this%
)

echo %fullstring%
pause
```

What this does is read back a string (string) character-by-character to another one (fullstring). I need to know how to overwrite the fullstring from the for loop.

Comment: I guess, you need to know, how `for`, `set` and  [delayed expanison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) are working.. The content of your `for /L` loop doesn't make much sense. Enter `for /?` and `set /?` and read their output.

Comment: Is that really your [MCVE]? Did you fail to show us your `SETLOCAL` command?

Comment: Please read [Ask]. The answer to your question probably wouldn't help you with whatever your current problem is. You failed to state exactly what your script is doing as it is written. If it was doing what you intended, you probably wouldn't be asking any questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "fullstring="
set "string=testago"

> x echo %string%

for %%? in (x) do set /a "strlength=%%~z? - 2"

del x

for /l %%a in (1,1,%strlength%) do (
    set /a "b=%%a - 1"
    call set "this=%%string:~!b!,1%%"
    set "fullstring=!fullstring!!this!"
)

echo "%fullstring%"
pause
```

In the `for /l` loop, no need for `c` variable so removed.

Use of `call set` to do a 2nd parse of the line to set `this` variable.
`b` requires delayed expansion then `string` variable needs expanding so
use of `call set` on `string` using doubled percentages achieves this.

The 2nd argument of the variable substitution is the length.
Character by character will be a constant 1 for length.

Concatenating the full string will require delayed expansion
or use of `call set` as an alternative.